# Rar all files in subdirectories individually

Tags: batch-file, rar, winrar

I'm trying to use a batch file to rar all files in subdirectory. I found the following script online, which does the job, but it creates the RAR compressed version of the files in the *parent* directory. I'd like them to remain in their original directory.

```
:sindiv
echo.
echo.
for /R %b IN (*.*) do (rar a "%~nb" "%b" )
)
goto eof
```

Comment: Replace `rar a "%~nb" "%b" ` by `rar a "%~dpnb" "%~b"`... In a batch file you need to double all the `%` signs around `b`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this solution :

```
@echo off
Set "rar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe"
for /R %%b IN (*.*) do ( 
    If /I not "%%~xb" == "rar" (
        If /I not "%%~nxb" == "%~nx0" (
            echo "%rar%" a "%%~dpnb.rar" "%%~dpnxb" 
            "%rar%" a "%%~dpnb.rar" "%%~dpnxb">nul 
        )   
    )   
)
pause
```

Comment: thanks hackoo.  this also does exactly what's needed, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your batch code just produces a syntax error message on execution because of not using `%%` instead of `%` on loop variable reference. Further there is an erroneous closing parenthesis and there is a `goto` which should jump to a label which does not exist.

I suggest to use the following batch code:

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.*) do (
    if /I not "%%~xI" == "rar" (
        if not exist "%%~dpnI.rar" (
            if not "%%~fI" == "%~f0" (
                "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep -idq -m5 -r- -tl -y -- "%%~dpnI" "%%I"
            )
        )
    )
)
goto :EOF
```

Command **FOR** finds all files with hidden or system file attribute not set in current directory and all subdirectories.

The first case-insensitive **IF** checks if the current file is not a *.rar file to avoid the recompression of *.rar files.

The second **IF** checks if there is not already a *.rar file for the current file in same directory as the file to avoid a recompression of a file compressed perhaps already before with a previous execution of the batch file.

The third **IF** excludes the batch file from compression if the batch file is also stored in current directory.

For the switches used on compressing a file read the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of WinRAR which is the manual for the console version explaining the switches.

`goto eof` requires that there is a label `eof` somewhere in the batch file. But `goto :EOF` is a special command extension of command **GOTO** to exit processing of a batch file or a subroutine not requiring a label `EOF` and being available when command extensions are enabled as by default.

The batch file above might work for your task, but there is one issue. Let's assume a directory contains the files `MyTestFile.csv` and `MyTestFile.txt`. The code above would compress `MyTestFile.csv` (on NTFS drive, on a FAT32 drive it could be also the *.txt file instead of the *.csv file) to `MyTestFile.rar` and the other file having same file name, but a different file extension is ignored completely as there is already a `MyTestFile.rar` present in the directory.

So what to do to get both files into same RAR file?

**Solution 1:**

Add all files with same file name but different file extension into a RAR archive file by replacing `"%%I"` with `"%%~dpnI.*"` and use the exclude switch `-x` to exclude a *.rar file matched also by this file name pattern.

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.*) do (
    if /I not "%%~xI" == "rar" (
        if not exist "%%~dpnI.rar" (
            if not "%%~fI" == "%~f0" (
                "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep -idq -m5 -r- -tl -x*.rar -y -- "%%~dpnI" "%%~dpnI.*"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Solution 2:**

Add only files to the RAR archive which have the archive attribute currently set and clear the archive attribute after adding the file to the archive. This solution has also the advantage that second **IF** condition is not needed at all and a file modified since last compression is updated in archive on running the batch file once again.

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.*) do (
    if /I not "%%~xI" == "rar" (
        if not "%%~fI" == "%~f0" (
            "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ac -ao -cfg- -ep -idq -m5 -r- -tl -y -- "%%~dpnI" "%%I"
        )
    )
)
```

This second solution could be also without the two additional **IF** conditions by using the exclude switch `-x` twice to exclude all files with file extension RAR and also the batch file itself.

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.*) do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ac -ao -cfg- -ep -idq -m5 -r- -tl -x*.rar -x"%~f0" -y -- "%%~dpnI" "%%I"
```

But this would be slower than previous code with the additional **IF** conditions as starting `Rar.exe` for doing nothing is slower than two string comparisons done by Windows command processor.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`

And of course read text file `Rar.txt` from top to bottom at least once.

Comment: Hi Mofi, thanks! this is great, does exactly what's needed (and more)